# check name of file if include substring

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I browse directory and checking all files by for loop.

```
for %%f in (*.doc ) do (
  echo full name: %%f
  echo name without suffix: %%~nxf
)
```

For example files like this "1234-important.doc"
I need somehow recognize what is between '-' and '.doc' and and set this value into variable flag to next processing.

```
IF [$flag] == [*"-important"*] (
  echo important
)
```

Do you have any suggestions how to do it ?
Maybe use some regex on file name ?

Comment: I think that the `forfiles` feature is what you need.

Comment: Why do you not use `for %%f in ("*-important*.doc") do ...` to find and process only document files containing the string `-important` in file name?

Comment: @Mofi
because in future there will be more flags than one and I want create universal script that will check this part of file name

Comment: @wdfeww, but you could easily add those to your `FOR` command. `FOR %%f in (*-important.doc *-classified.doc *-sensitive.doc) do ......`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code works if there is only one hyphen in your file name.  It uses a nested FOR command to split the base file name by the hyphen.

```
@echo off
for %%F in (*.doc ) do (
    echo full name: %%F
    echo name without suffix: %%~nF
    for /F "tokens=2 delims=-" %%G IN ("%%~nF") DO (
        IF /I "%%G"=="important" (echo File is important) else Echo File is not important
    )
)
```

This second set of code checks if the base file name ends in the string you are looking for by using the `FINDSTR` command.  Conditional execution is then used to determine which echo command is executed.  The double ampersand is used to execute if the previous command was successful. The double pipe is used to execute if the previous command was not successful.

```
for %%F in (*.doc ) do (
    set "flag="
    echo full name: %%F
    echo name without suffix: %%~nF
    echo %%~nF|findstr /E /I "important" >nul 2>&1 &&echo File is Important || echo file is not important
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an example where the filename is used too:

```
forfiles /M *important* /C "cmd /c echo @file : important"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that searches for files containing a string. The `STR` variable can be set to whatever is being sought.

```
SET "STR=*-important*"
FOR /F "delims=" %%f IN ('DIR /B "%STR%" 2^>NUL') DO (
    ECHO %%~f
)
```